# Let $f(x) = \operatorname{max}(\sin x; \cos x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis

I was thinking about the following problem:

> Let $f(x) = \operatorname{max}(\sin x; \cos x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$. Then
>
> a. $f$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R$.
>
> b. $f$ is nowhere differentiable.
>
> c. $f$ is differentiable except at $0$.
>
> d. $f$ is differentiable except at a countable set of points.
>
> e. none of the above.

My Try:  Let $\sin x \ge \cos x$ for some $x \in \Bbb R$ .Then $f(x)=\sin x $ which is differentiable at $0$ and so option
(c) can not be right.That means (b) is also false. I think option (a) is the correct choice. But I am also confused about
option (d).

Similar case will follow if we take  $\sin x \le \cos x$ for some $x \in \Bbb R$ .Then $f(x)=\cos x $.

Can someone give  explanation? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I think $f$ fails to be differentiable at countably many points.. I am not able to tell exact reason but i feel it should be the case

Comment: Thanks @PraphullaKoushik for your interest. To verify option (d), we need to come up with at least one  example where $f$ is not differentiable and that is where i am stuck.

Comment: look for the comments of below answer for example....

Comment: At $0$, $f(x)=\cos{x}$, since $\cos{0}\gt\sin{0}$, so your argument should be $f(0)=\cos{0}$ and $f(x)=\cos{x}$ in the interval $(\frac{-3\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4})$ and thus $c$ and $b$ are out..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try drawing the graphs of $y=\sin x$ and $y=\cos x$. Then you must choose the graph that lies above the other. It will be pretty clear that the function $f$ has countably many points (the solutions of $\sin x = \cos x$) where you glue $\sin x$ on one ice and $\cos x$ on the opposite side. To answer (d), you should check if this gluing is differentiable.

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BMax%5BSin%5Bx%5D,Cos%5Bx%5D%5D,%7Bx,-20,20%7D%5D) is the graph of $f$.

Comment: are you saying $f$ has countably many point where it is not differentiable?? I also feel  the same..

Comment: Yes, it should be clear from the graph. Of course one should provide a rigorous proof.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: it's not differentiable at $\dfrac{k\pi}{4}$ and $\dfrac{5k\pi}{4}$, since at those points the derivative from either side are $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Comment: @Siminore : do you have some idea to prove rigorously...

Comment: Oh yes: find explicitly the intersection points, then study the left- and the right-derivative of $f$ at those points.